# Iterate in a JSON array and style its elements

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am fetching data from a REST API, and I am receive a JSON that has the following format:

```
[Object]
 0:Object
  createdAt:"2016-05-04T16:32"
 list:Array[4]
    0:"Mango"
    1:"Apple"
    2:"Banana"
    3:"Kiwi"
```

Currently, the following is printed when calling that JSON in the HTML file:

> Mango,Apple,Banana,Kiwi

Here is the JS code used to retrieve data from the REST API:

```
this.http.get('https://example.com/api').subscribe(data => {
    this.categories = data.json().results;
    });
```

The current HTML/Angular code:

```
  <div *ngFor="#fruit of categories">
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
     <div class="txt">{{fruit.list}}</div>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
```

The final Result of what I want to achieve is the following:

```
 <div>

   <ion-row>
   <ion-col>
     <div class="txt">Mango</div>
   </ion-col>
   <ion-col>
     <div class="txt">Apple</div>
   </ion-col>
   </ion-row>

   <ion-row>
   <ion-col>
     <div class="txt">Banana</div>
   </ion-col>
   <ion-col>
     <div class="txt">Kiwi</div>
   </ion-col>
   </ion-row>

   </div>
```

Can you please tell me how to achieve that? Do I need to change something on the JSON itself? Or it can be done simply by tweaking the *ngFor?

Comment: what's `categories`? And...the result you want to achieve isn't possible with one loop.

Comment: I've done an edit, so you can see clearly what is `categories` hope this helps!

Comment: I'm confused by your subject. You say you are interested in styling, but it looks more like you are interested in grouping in a parent row element by some category property that I do not see in the JSON? I think your JSON should have a first order category array, then each category would have a child fruit array. Then you could ngFor on group, then fruit within the group.

Comment: FYI, JSON is a text format for data. So the moment you can access it as an object or array and it isn't a string, it's no longer JSON. See [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for more information.

Comment: @JohnMcCann you may see it from different perspectives, as for me I see it to create a `<ion-row>` for each and every two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new object to gather elements:

```
this.service.getFruits().subscribe(categories => {
  let fruits = categories.list;
  let fruitsByGroup = [];
  fruits.forEach((fruit, index) => {
    let groupIndex = Math.floor(index/2);
    if (index%2 === 0) {
      fruitsByGroup[groupIndex] = [];
    }
    fruitsByGroup[groupIndex].push(fruit);
  });

  this.fruitsByGroup = fruitsByGroup;
});
```

Then I would iterate this way:

```
<div *ngFor="#fruitGroup of fruitsByGroup">
  <ion-row *ngFor="#fruit of fruitGroup">
    <ion-col>
     <div class="txt">{{fruit.list}}</div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry, I've tried that but I am getting an error: `TypeError: fruits.forEach is not a function` any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You're welcome! The error is because I missed the `list` property in your response content... I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That's true, I was iterating over an object instead of an array!

Comment: By the way, it will be veeery helpful and knowledgable if you can tell me the idea behind/how it's working so I learn! And thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using an ng-repeat:

```
     <div>
       <ion-row ng-repeat="fruit in categories.list">
           <ion-col>
             <div class="txt">{{fruit}}</div>
           </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
    </div>
```

The main complication that will come out of this, is separating them out into different rows.  If there aren't too many items you're dealing with, you could try something like this:

```
     <div>
       <ion-row ng-repeat="fruit in categories.list.slice(0,1)">
           <ion-col>
             <div class="txt">{{fruit}}</div>
           </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
       <ion-row ng-repeat="fruit in categories.list.slice(2,3)">
           <ion-col>
             <div class="txt">{{fruit}}</div>
           </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
    </div>
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using nested ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="#fruit of categories">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="#item of fruit.list"> 
      <div class="txt">
         {{item}} 
      </div>
   </ion-col> 
  </ion-row> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In you rest calling code

```
this.http.get('https://example.com/api').subscribe(data => {
this.categories = data.json().results[0].list;
});
```

In your HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="#fruit of categories">
 <ion-row>
  <ion-col>
  <div class="txt">{{fruit[0]}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  </div>
```